# Pandas DataFrame grouped box plot from aggregated results

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, dataframe

I want to draw box plot, but I don't have raw data but aggregated results in Pandas DataFrame.

Is it still possible to draw box plot from the aggregated results?

If not, what is the closest plot that I can get, to plot the min, max, mean, median, std-dev etc. I know I can plot them using line chart, but I need the boxplots to be grouped/clustered.

Here is my data, the plotting part is missing. Please help. Thanks

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'group' : ['Tick Tick Tick', 'Tock Tock Tock', 'Tock Tock Tock', 'Tick Tick Tick']*3, # , ['Tock Tock Tock', 'Tick Tick Tick']*6,
        'person':[x*5 for x in list('ABC')]*4,
        'Median':np.random.randn(12),
        'StdDev':np.random.randn(12)
                   })
df["Average"]=df["Median"]*1.1
df["Minimum"]=df["Median"]*0.5
df["Maximum"]=df["Median"]*1.6
df["90%"]=df["Maximum"]*0.9
df["95%"]=df["Maximum"]*0.95
df["99%"]=df["Maximum"]*0.99

df
```

**UPDATE**,

I'm now one step closer to get my result -- I have just found that this feature was [available since matplotlib 1.4](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2643), and I'm using matplotlib 1.5, and I tested it and [proved that it is working for me](https://gist.github.com/suntong/56490c89220592fa7409).

The problem is I have no clue why it works, and how to adapt my above code to use such new feature. I'll re-post my working code below, hope someone can understand and put two and two together.

The data I have are Median, Average, Minimum, 90%,95%, 99%, Maximum and StdDev, and I hope to chart them all. and I took a look at the data structure of `logstats` of the following code, after the `for stats, label in zip(logstats, list('ABCD'))`, and found its fields are:

```
[{'cihi': 4.2781254505311281,
  'cilo': 1.6164348064249057,
  'fliers': array([ 19.69118642,  19.01171604]),
  'iqr': 5.1561885723613567,
  'label': 'A',
  'mean': 4.9486856766955922,
  'med': 2.9472801284780168,
  'q1': 1.7655440553898782,
  'q3': 6.9217326277512345,
  'whishi': 12.576334012545718,
  'whislo': 0.24252084924003742},
 {'cihi': 4.3186289184254107,
  'cilo': 1.9963715983778565,
  ...
```

So, from this

[image: box plot]

and the `bxp` doc, I'm going to map my data as follows:

- whislo: Minimum
- q1: Median
- med: Average
- mean: 90%
- q3: 95%
- whishi: 99%
- and Maximum as fliers

To map them, I'll just do `SELECT Minimum AS whislo, [90%] AS mean, [95%] as q3, [99%] as whishi`...Here is the final result:

```
raw_data = {'label': ['Label_01 Init', 'Label_02', 'Label_03', 'Label_04', 'Label_05', 'Label_06', 'Label_07', 'Label_08', 'Label_99'], 'whislo': [0.17999999999999999, 2.0299999999999998, 4.0800000000000001, 2.0899999999999999, 2.3300000000000001, 2.3799999999999999, 1.97, 2.6499999999999999, 0.089999999999999997], 'q3': [0.5, 4.9699999999999998, 11.77, 5.71, 12.460000000000001, 11.859999999999999, 13.84, 16.969999999999999, 0.29999999999999999], 'mean': [0.40000000000000002, 4.1299999999999999, 10.619999999999999, 5.0999999999999996, 10.24, 9.0700000000000003, 11.960000000000001, 15.15, 0.26000000000000001], 'whishi': [1.76, 7.6399999999999997, 20.039999999999999, 6.6699999999999999, 22.460000000000001, 21.66, 16.629999999999999, 19.690000000000001, 1.1799999999999999], 'q1': [0.28000000000000003, 2.96, 7.6100000000000003, 3.46, 5.8099999999999996, 5.4400000000000004, 6.6299999999999999, 8.9900000000000002, 0.16], 'fliers': [5.5, 17.129999999999999, 32.890000000000001, 7.9100000000000001, 32.829999999999998, 70.680000000000007, 24.699999999999999, 32.240000000000002, 3.3500000000000001]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['label', 'whislo', 'q1', 'mean', 'q3', 'whishi', 'fliers'])
```

Now to challenge is how to present my above dataframe in box plot with multiple level of grouping. If multiple level of grouping is too difficult, let's get the plotting from pd dataframe working first, because my `pd` dataframe has the same fields as the required `np` array. So I tried,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bxp(df.as_matrix(), showmeans=True, showfliers=True, vert=False)
```

But I got

```
...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in bxp(self, bxpstats, positions, widths, vert, patch_artist, shownotches, showmeans, showcaps, showbox, showfliers, boxprops, whiskerprops, flierprops, medianprops, capprops, meanprops, meanline, manage_xticks)
   3601         for pos, width, stats in zip(positions, widths, bxpstats):
   3602             # try to find a new label
-> 3603             datalabels.append(stats.get('label', pos))
   3604             # fliers coords
   3605             flier_x = np.ones(len(stats['fliers'])) * pos

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get'
```

If I use `ax.bxp(df.to_records(), ...`, then I'll get `AttributeError: 'record' object has no attribute 'get'`.

OK, I finally got it working, the plotting from pd dataframe, but not multiple level of grouping, like this:

```
df['fliers']=''
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bxp(df.to_dict('records'), showmeans=True, meanline=True, showfliers=False, vert=False) # shownotches=True, 
plt.show()
```

Note my above data is missing the `med` field, you can add the correct ones, or use `df['med']=df['q1']*1.2` to make it works.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def test_bxp_with_ylabels():
    np.random.seed(937)
    logstats = matplotlib.cbook.boxplot_stats(
        np.random.lognormal(mean=1.25, sigma=1., size=(37,4))
    )
    print(logstats)
    for stats, label in zip(logstats, list('ABCD')):
        stats['label'] = label

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_xscale('log')
    ax.bxp(logstats, vert=False)

test_bxp_with_ylabels()
```

[image: bxp_with_ylabels]

Comment: I don't understand what data you have and how many boxplot you expect. `ax.bxp` expects median, quartiles and whisker values. Do you have that ?

Comment: So far I understood that you only have `p` and `e` and that you want to make a box plot with the value in `p` as the mean and the value in `e` as the std, somehow plot ` p ± e `, is that what you want ?

Comment: ok, and was the grouping of the boxplot right in my answer ? Also in your dataframe, you have multiple values for the median for a given pair (group;person),  shall I use the mean of those values ? (as you did before with the `pivot_table`?)

Comment: Yes, I do need them grouped, i.e., your answer was correct. I was just have no clue to how to make it happen so I removed the `pivot_table` statement, just to emphasizing the original data source. As for data mapping, according to your new explanation, I'll just do `SELECT Minimum  AS whislo, [90%] AS q3, [95%] as whishi...`. The next challenge is how to present it with multiple level of grouping. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

While waiting a clarification of your df, related to:

```
dic = [{'cihi': 4.2781254505311281,
        'cilo': 1.6164348064249057,
        'fliers': array([ 19.69118642,  19.01171604]),
        'iqr': 5.1561885723613567,
        'mean': 4.9486856766955922,
        'med': 2.9472801284780168,
        'q1': 1.7655440553898782,
        'q3': 6.9217326277512345,
        'whishi': 12.576334012545718,
        'whislo': 0.24252084924003742}]
```

and how your data should map:

from `bxp` doc:

```
  Required keys are:

  - ``med``: The median (scalar float).    
  - ``q1``: The first quartile (25th percentile) (scalar
    float).
  - ``q3``: The first quartile (50th percentile) (scalar
    float). # Here I guess it's rather : the 3rd quartile (75th percentile)
  - ``whislo``: Lower bound of the lower whisker (scalar
    float).
  - ``whishi``: Upper bound of the upper whisker (scalar
    float).

  Optional keys are:

  - ``mean``: The mean (scalar float). Needed if
    ``showmeans=True``.
  - ``fliers``: Data beyond the whiskers (sequence of floats).
    Needed if ``showfliers=True``.
  - ``cilo`` & ``cihi``: Lower and upper confidence intervals
    about the median. Needed if ``shownotches=True``.
```

Then, you just have to do:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.bxp([dic], showmeans=True)
```

So you just need to find a way to build your `dic`. Note that it does not plot your `std` and for the whisker, you need to choose whether they go up to 90%, 95% or 99% but you can't have all values. In that case you need to add them afterward with something like `plt.hlines()`.

HTH

Comment: Thanks jeanrjc for your help. I finally got it working, i.e., get the plotting from pd dataframe working, but not multiple level of grouping. Will update my OP later.